# how we can predict stock price based on 2 or more features in keras lstm?

Tags: python, keras, lstm, prediction

i want to predict stock future price. but the problem is that when i want predict future close price based on 2 feature (close and open price for example), i get error. the code is this:

my question is that : how can i add other feature (for example, open price or volume and the other) to this code and do forecast future close price based on this combination features?!
thanks for your future help! :))

enter code here

```
#import libraries
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import yfinance as yf
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Dense, LSTM
from tensorflow.keras.models import Sequential
from sklearn.preprocessing import MinMaxScaler
pd.options.mode.chained_assignment = None
tf.random.set_seed(0)

# download the data
df = yf.download(tickers=['AAPL'], period='1y')
y = df['Close'].fillna(method='ffill')
y = y.values.reshape(-1, 1)

# scale the data
scaler = MinMaxScaler(feature_range=(0, 1))
scaler = scaler.fit(y)
y = scaler.transform(y)

# generate the input and output sequences
n_lookback = 60  # length of input sequences (lookback period)
n_forecast = 60 # length of output sequences (forecast period)

X = []
Y = []

for i in range(n_lookback, len(y) - n_forecast + 1):
    X.append(y[i - n_lookback: i])
    Y.append(y[i: i + n_forecast])

X = np.array(X)
Y = np.array(Y)

#fit the model
model = Sequential()
model.add(LSTM(units=50, return_sequences=True, input_shape=(n_lookback, 1)))
model.add(LSTM(units=50))
model.add(Dense(n_forecast))
model.compile(loss='mean_squared_error', optimizer='adam')
model.fit(X, Y, epochs=100, batch_size=32, verbose=0)

# generate the forecasts
X_ = y[- n_lookback:]  # last available input sequence
X_ = X_.reshape(1, n_lookback, 1)

Y_ = model.predict(X_).reshape(-1, 1)
Y_ = scaler.inverse_transform(Y_)

# organize the results in a data frame
df_past = df[['Close']].reset_index()
df_past.rename(columns={'index': 'Date', 'Close': 'Actual'}, inplace=True)
df_past['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df_past['Date'])
df_past['Forecast'] = np.nan
df_past['Forecast'].iloc[-1] = df_past['Actual'].iloc[-1]

df_future = pd.DataFrame(columns=['Date', 'Actual', 'Forecast'])
df_future['Date'] = pd.date_range(start=df_past['Date'].iloc[-1] + pd.Timedelta(days=1), periods=n_forecast)
df_future['Forecast'] = Y_.flatten()
df_future['Actual'] = np.nan
results = df_past.append(df_future).set_index('Date')

the changes that i apply on the sections of the code there is below:

    enter code here

# download the data
df1 = yf.download(tickers=['AAPL'], period='max',interval='1d')
y1 = df1['Close'].fillna(method='ffill')
y1 = y1.values.reshape(-1, 1)
y2 = df1['Open'].fillna(method='ffill')
y2 = y2.values.reshape(-1, 1)
y3 = [*y1 , *y2]
y1 = df1[['Close','Open']]
y = np.array(y1).T  

i convert the 2 inputs (close & open) to array and get that to y and the output is below:

[*********************100%***********************]  1 of 1 completed

array([[1.28347993e-01, 1.21652000e-01, 1.12723000e-01, ...,
        1.56570007e+02, 1.63639999e+02, 1.57649994e+02],
       [1.28347993e-01, 1.22210003e-01, 1.13280997e-01, ...,
        1.55910004e+02, 1.59250000e+02, 1.61839996e+02]])

the problem is when i want to get merged input to the input of model:
 

    enter code here

#fit the model
model = Sequential()
model.add(LSTM(units=50, return_sequences=True, input_shape=(n_lookback, 1)))
model.add(LSTM(units=50))
model.add(Dense(n_forecast))
model.compile(loss='mean_squared_error', optimizer='adam')
model.fit(X, Y, epochs=100, batch_size=32, verbose=0)
model.summary()

the error of top section of code is that : 

WARNING:tensorflow:Model was constructed with shape (None, 1, 1) for input KerasTensor(type_spec=TensorSpec(shape=(None, 1, 1), dtype=tf.float32, name='lstm_309_input'), name='lstm_309_input', description="created by layer 'lstm_309_input'"), but it was called on an input with incompatible shape (None, 1, 10434).

---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
Input In [1594], in <cell line: 7>()
      5 model.add(Dense(n_forecast))
      6 model.compile(loss='mean_squared_error', optimizer='adam')
----> 7 model.fit(X, Y, epochs=100, batch_size=32, verbose=0)
      8 model.summary()

File E:\anaconda\envs\time_series\lib\site-packages\keras\utils\traceback_utils.py:67, in filter_traceback.<locals>.error_handler(*args, **kwargs)
     65 except Exception as e:  # pylint: disable=broad-except
     66   filtered_tb = _process_traceback_frames(e.__traceback__)
---> 67   raise e.with_traceback(filtered_tb) from None
     68 finally:
     69   del filtered_tb

File E:\anaconda\envs\time_series\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\framework\func_graph.py:1147, in func_graph_from_py_func.<locals>.autograph_handler(*args, **kwargs)
   1145 except Exception as e:  # pylint:disable=broad-except
   1146   if hasattr(e, "ag_error_metadata"):
-> 1147     raise e.ag_error_metadata.to_exception(e)
   1148   else:
   1149     raise

ValueError: in user code:

    File "E:\anaconda\envs\time_series\lib\site-packages\keras\engine\training.py", line 1021, in train_function  *
        return step_function(self, iterator)
    File "E:\anaconda\envs\time_series\lib\site-packages\keras\engine\training.py", line 1010, in step_function  **
        outputs = model.distribute_strategy.run(run_step, args=(data,))
    File "E:\anaconda\envs\time_series\lib\site-packages\keras\engine\training.py", line 1000, in run_step  **
        outputs = model.train_step(data)
    File "E:\anaconda\envs\time_series\lib\site-packages\keras\engine\training.py", line 859, in train_step
        y_pred = self(x, training=True)
    File "E:\anaconda\envs\time_series\lib\site-packages\keras\utils\traceback_utils.py", line 67, in error_handler
        raise e.with_traceback(filtered_tb) from None
    File "E:\anaconda\envs\time_series\lib\site-packages\keras\engine\input_spec.py", line 264, in assert_input_compatibility
        raise ValueError(f'Input {input_index} of layer "{layer_name}" is '

    ValueError: Exception encountered when calling layer "sequential_138" (type Sequential).
    
    Input 0 of layer "lstm_309" is incompatible with the layer: expected shape=(None, None, 1), found shape=(None, 1, 10434)
    
    Call arguments received:
      • inputs=tf.Tensor(shape=(None, 1, 10434), dtype=float32)
      • training=True
      • mask=None
```

Comment: Exactly what error are you getting and where is the code failing?

Comment: i want put 2 or more input values for example open, high, low and even volume! but in the train section, i don't know how merge 2 or more input into one input and take that to the model.